# When designing a system how could I describe the way sequence diagrams are related?

Tags: design, uml

After the sequence diagram are made the sequence methods become code, before writing some code that would alter database records I would like to know how to detect if a sequence is doing the job without damaging some other part's of the system, what comes to my mind is that there must be a way to relate the sequences to something so that it would be easy to analyze by having a high-level document to keep track of.

Comment: Sequence diagrams are just planning tools, unless you intend to build some sort of code generator that *creates* software based on the diagrams.   Diagrams do not guarantee system integrity; well-written, tested and documented ***code*** does that.

Comment: In any case, to help maintain this kind of system integrity, design the software in such a way that each of its modules communicates with each other only through **strict, well-defined boundaries.**  Then you won't have to worry about one part of the system damaging another part, because each part is responsible for its own business.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface for more information.

Comment: Sure, sequence diagrams do not guarantee system integrity, but they do give a point of reference to analyze before the implementation phase, thanks for the boundaries suggestion @RobertHarvey

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend drawing a class diagram or a component diagram showing the classes of objects that participate in your sequence diagrams.

- The messages in your sequence diagrams should match the operations defined on the classes.
- The relationships among the classes should reflect which classes interact with which other classes. For example, if method X of class A calls method Y of class B, then you could draw a dependency arrow from A to B in the class diagram.

If you have complex interactions and you want to divide such a complex interaction over multiple sequence diagrams, you could use an interaction overview diagram. This resembles an activity diagram, where each action is a (reference to a) sequence diagram or other kind of interaction diagram. The following image is copied from the UML 2.5 specification.

[image: IOD]